# Colorize white silhouette with Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I have a white shape with transparent background and I want to change it with some arbitrary color in order to obtain a colored silhouette. The input could be a SVG or PNG. The output must be a PNG file.

In the following example I'm trying to change a white circle to red but it doesn't work. I think that I'm not understanding what `colorizeImage` and `tintImage` functions does.

```
<?php
$svg = <<<SVG
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="150" height="150">
   <ellipse style="fill:#ffffff" cx="50" cy="50" rx="50" ry="50" />
</svg>
SVG;

$color = '#FF0000';

$img = new \Imagick();
$img->readImageBlob($svg);
$img->setImageBackgroundColor('transparent');

//My tries
$test = clone $img;
$test->tintImage($color, 0, true);
$test->writeImage(__DIR__ . '/out_tint_0.png');

$test = clone $img;
$test->tintImage($color, 1.0, true);
$test->writeImage(__DIR__ . '/out_tint_1.png');

$test = clone $img;
$test->colorizeImage($color, 0, true);
$test->writeImage(__DIR__ . '/out_colorize_0.png');

$test = clone $img;
$test->colorizeImage($color, 1.0, true);
$test->writeImage(__DIR__ . '/out_colorize_1.png');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a image of the same size with plain color and then composite with the original one considering only the alpha channel

```
$base_color = new \Imagick();
$base_color->newImage($img->getImageWidth(), $img->getImageHeight(), '#ff8a00');
$base_color->compositeImage($img, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0);
```

Full example

```
<?php
$svg = <<<SVG
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="150" height="150">
   <ellipse style="fill:#ffffff" cx="50" cy="50" rx="50" ry="50" />
</svg>
SVG;

$color = '#FF0000';

$img = new \Imagick();
$img->readImageBlob($svg);
$img->setImageBackgroundColor('transparent');

$base_color = new \Imagick();
$base_color->newImage($img->getImageWidth(), $img->getImageHeight(), '#ff8a00');
$base_color->compositeImage($img, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0);
$base_color->writeImage(__DIR__ . '/out_colorize_1.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use Imagick to edit SVG.
Just add in CSS: `background-color: #000;`

Comment: Thanks, but a SVG input is a particular case. The input file could be a PNG also.  I edited the question to make it clear